# Spark httpclient job does not parallel well

Tags: scala, http, apache-spark

I am new to scala/spark. I need to write a spark job that makes API get calls based on an input urls.txt file. Below is my sample codes. I think the Await below is throttling the job, but I can't think of methods to achieve my goal better due to my limited experiences. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
object MyApp extends App {

  val partitions = 10
  val textFile = sc.textFile(s"file:///tmp/urls.txt",partitions)
  val futures = textFile.flatMap(url => {
    val wsclient = InitializeConfigurations.getWSClient()
    var future = wsclient.url(url).withRequestTimeout(10 seconds).get().map(response => {
        s"${response.body}"
    })

    future onComplete {
      case Success(res) =>
        println(s"oncomplete: res = $res")
      case Failure(ex) =>
        ex match {
          case t: TimeoutException => None
          case _ =>
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }      

    Some(future)
   })

  val hresps = futures.flatMap(f => {
    try {
      val line = Await.result(f, 10 seconds)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        None
      }
    }
  })

  hresps.saveAsTextFile(s"file:///tmp/a01.txt")
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. It helped.

Comment: consider upvoting the comment in that case, if you can.

Comment: I would have but I cannot. I searched. Some posts said that I would need some reputations to be able to upvote a comment. Sorry but thanks for your help.